# How to get text from AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android

I need your help in getting string value on refresh,  and displaying it in AlertDialog. I would like to COPY TEXT TO NEW STRING on copy button click

and want to add "COPY" button in AlertDialog

```
String plain ="hello;" // changing on refresh

new AlertDialog.Builder(Demo.this)
.setTitle("New Message")
.setMessage(plain)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
.setCancelable(false)
.create().show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978393/android-get-retrieve-progressdialog-titles-id-and-dialegerror-titles-id

Answer (score 6):

If you want to message from alert dialog then try below code

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)YOUR_ALERT_DIALOG.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
 Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), ""+tv.getText());
```

If message is not set in your alert dialog it will throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello Pooja, Here is code for your need

```
public class Blah extends Activity {
private String result;

// other activity stuff

void showDialog(){

String plain="hello";

AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
b.setTitle("Please enter a password");
b.setMessage(plain)
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
b.setView(input);
b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
    {
       // SHOULD NOW WORK
       result = plain;
    }
});
b.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
b.create().show();
}
}
```

Comment: i dont want input i want to copy from .setMessage

Comment: hi @Pooja ,it's so simple get that string in onClick listener i.e. in onClick listener result =plain

Answer (score 0):

Add a neutral button and set its listener like this :

```
final String plain ="hello;" // changing on refresh
String copy;

new AlertDialog.Builder(Demo.this)
.setTitle("New Message")
.setMessage(plain)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
.setNeutralButton("COPY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    copy = plain;
                }
            })
.setCancelable(false)
.create().show();
```